# gem 'authlogic' stack level too deep after upgrade to rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I'm getting the following error after upgrading from 'rails', '2.3.15' to 'rails', '3.2.17'

```
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 320.9ms

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  .bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70
```

I know the error is somewhere in following method:

```
def current_user
  return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
  @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
  Authorization.current_user = @current_user
end
```

Would be awesome if someone that has implemented authlogic with rails 3 can give me some hints.

Thanks a lot!

Here is my full application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

      helper :all # include all helpers, all the time
      helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user
      helper_method :current_user
      helper_method :current_division

      rescue_from Authorization::AttributeAuthorizationError, :with => :rescue_auth_error

      protect_from_forgery # See ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection for details

      # Scrub sensitive parameters from your log

      around_filter :clear_current_user

      before_filter :require_user
      before_filter :configure_mailers

      private


      def rescue_auth_error(exception)
        if current_user.present?
          UserSession.find(current_user.id).destroy
          flash[:error] = "Your session has expired. Please log in again."
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      end

      def clear_current_user
        remove_instance_variable :@current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        remove_instance_variable :@current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
        yield
        remove_instance_variable :@current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        remove_instance_variable :@current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
        Authorization.current_user = nil
      end

      def current_user_session
        return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session) && !@current_user_session.nil?
        @current_user_session = UserSession.find
        # @current_user_session = current_division.user_sessions.find
      end

      def current_user
        return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
        @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.record
        Authorization.current_user = @current_user
      end

      def require_user
        unless current_user
          store_location
          # flash[:notice] = "You must be logged in to access this page"
          redirect_to new_user_session_url
          return false
        end
      end

      def require_no_user
        if current_user
          store_location
          # flash[:notice] = "You must be logged out to access this page"
          redirect_to account_url
          return false
        end
      end

      def store_location
        session[:return_to] = request.request_uri
      end

      def redirect_back_or_default(default)
        redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
        session[:return_to] = nil
      end

      def current_division
        @current_division ||= Division.find_by_code('prd')
      end

      def configure_mailers
        Notifier.configure(request)
      end

      def permission_denied
        flash[:error] = "You do not have permission to access that page."
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end
```

Comment: What version of authlogic?

Comment: It's 3.4.2 did bundle update authlogic after rails upgrade

Comment: That sounds like an endless loop is running, which is a weird error to get.  Which version of ruby are you using?  I think the quickest way out of errors that occur on an update is usually to just reinstall rails, or your ruby version.  If you updated rails you may want to update ruby too.

Comment: I updated ruby to 1.9.3... seems to be an issue with authlogic: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited/issues/21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem was causing the error:

```
gem 'rd_searchlogic', :require => 'searchlogic', :git => 'git://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic.git'
```

Replaced with:

```
gem 'ransack'
```

All is good now.

Comment: Note for the future or for other issues you (or others) may run into - rails 2.3.15 to 3.2.17 is a massive jump.  I recommend going one version at a time and fully testing (automated and manual) along the way.  For many applications this is the preferred less painful route.  In your example I certainly would go to 3.0 first (no asset compilation) first.  I would also go up to ruby 1.9.3 early in the process and consider 2.0.0 towards the end.  You want, very roughly for your rails version to be close to the ruby versions current at the time.  Else you may end up having to resolve rare bugs .